# Keyboard shortcut to open sound preferences?

Tags: sound, keyboard, shortcut-keys

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04 and was wondering if there is a way to open a specific system setting panel via a keyboard shortcut.

Basically, I'd like to have a hotkey to open the sound settings in order to quickly change between HDMI output and internal.

I believe this is possible because when you hit the superkey and type "sound" it'll take you directly to the sound settings, but i'm not sure how to implement that as a hotkey.

Any ideas?

Comment: As the question is generic to Gnome shell, and also applies to Ubuntu with Gnome, removing the POP-os reference makes it a valid question. Already provided an edit

Comment: @vanadium that's not how our scope works!

Comment: @Zanna Not sure how it works then. Does this mean that if I posted the same - edited - question, that it would be rejected? Would the question have been rejected if OP had not added the three extra words revealing he actually uses a derived distribution? This particular question is 100% applicable on Ubuntu desktop, which is why it can be reworded to fit the rules. I admit that I might be fully missing the point, though, and that there might be another reason why this would be off topic.

Comment: @Zanna please enlighten me why this question remains out of scope after an edit.

Comment: @vanadium I disapprove of such edits. On topic is basically defined as OP using using Ubuntu and trying to do something in it or perhaps with it (within reason). Such edits set a bad precedent because we are not interested in whether problems are *specific* to Ubuntu or not. Reviewers should not have to decide whether something is specific to another distro or not. It would be total chaos in here if we allowed questions about other distros as long as they were not "specific" to those other distros. See meta. But perhaps I should write a new meta post about this.

Comment: @Zanna, OK for me, but the phrase "If this question can be reworded to fit the rules in the help center, please edit the question." is also somewhat misleading in that respect. Policy would then better be to immediately remove questions where it appears another distro is used.

Comment: @vanadium agreed & agreed!

Answer (score 9):

On the command line, you can start the control settings with the command `gnome-control-center`. As such, `man gnome-control-center` provides information on how the program can be started. For you, the Sound panel can be automatically opened with the command

```
gnome-control-center sound
```

Thus, in Settings - Devices - Keyboard, create a new shortcut key, and assign this command to it.

Comment: Thanks so much!  I gave Windows 10 the boot last year and am still learning the little things like that, but am super stoked to have shortcut keys for the things I do on an everyday basis.  So far I have Terminal, gnome-system-monitor, Blender, Unity, and GIMP all activated with hotkeys, and am excited to add the sound prefs!  Thanks!

Comment: If this answer works for you, then it would be good to mark it as accepted.

Comment: That's exactly what i did since i was always searching for sound in menu every day for few times since i'm switching between speaker and headphones often so got tiered of it really. So i made a shortcut (Pause button - unused key on any keyboard) to bind to that command, its awesome now. Thank you!